# Memory (RAM) Clean Function for Oreo

Tags: android, android-service, android-tools-namespace

Unable to get the total size of memory use like "CLEAN MASTER" APP in only 8.0, rest of version are working fine. We are trying to search from last 10 days but unable to found anything if anyone has suggestions then kindly help us.

Note:- issue is only for 8.0

[image: Like This image]

Comment: Don't use these kind of apps, they do nothing useful. Android is very well equipped to handle its memory.

Comment: Thanks but We are developing app like that so we must need solution of that :(

Comment: Don't. Put your efforts into something more useful.